# Apache Ubuntu Default Page not Loading

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, apache2, ubuntu-16.04

I am working on a new site, and I am spinning up a new server. I have ran into an issue I never have before. After installing LAMP on the server (Ubuntu 16.04), I am not receiving the default Apache Ubuntu page. I am getting this error:

```
13.59.41.148 took too long to respond.
```

I have started many servers with LAMP using Digital Ocean in the past, but this is my first time with AWS EC2. Could there possibly be something that I am missing that I have to do with this new host?

Comment: Post your security group configuration. Make sure you instance is in a public subnet with an IGW and you have port 80 (HTTP) open in your security group. Check your Apache logs to make sure there are no server errors.

Comment: No errors in the error log or access log. Not quite sure about the security groups but it has the default one assigned to it. And not sure about the public network either. Do you have a link for reference on how to check those things?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your instance has a public IP assigned already, the issue is the security groups.

Check the default group, you will have ssh port (22) open to 0.0.0.0/0 which means to the entire world as I was able to hit your instance over IP/22.

You can use nc utility to check connections[ IP port ]

```
nc -vz 13.59.41.148 22
```

To double check that Apache is loading the default page, you can always ssh to the server and curl localhost

```
curl localhost:80
```

Simply add network rule to the security group allowing 80 from 0.0.0.0/0 if you wish to have traffic opened to everyone.

However, better solution after the testing phase would be to setup Load Balancer in front of ec2 hosting the website. That Ec2 would be then hosted in private network, and traffic would be forwarded from Load Balancer hosted in public network.

You should probably also limit access over 22 to only your IP/network.

have a read on security groups basics: 
[AWS docs - Security groups](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_SecurityGroups.html#VPCSecurityGroups)

Comment: Thank you! The security groups was the issue, something I didn't even know I had to bother with!

Comment: your answer is a life saver :-)

Answer (score 5):

Amazon's AWS Solution

For those setting up on Amazon's AWS, ensure you are manually typing http:// instead of clicking the default link on their dashboard.
I had a similar issue just after installing Apache on Ubuntu 20.

I solved the issue by manually typing the address in my browser and ensuring the address had http://[IP_Address] instead of clicking the default link that is given by Amazon AWS as that has https:// by default.

Ultimately, ensure your Security Groups allow http (Port 80) Incoming and Outgoing traffic.

Also, ensure you have assigned the Security Group to your running instance.

If you have not set up your SSL as yet the address will not open so ensure you have http:// instead of https:// when trying to open your default address.